# Gini Impurity calculation with larger than 2 classes

Tags: machine-learning, classification, gini

I'm currently training a decision tree ML model. Everywhere I look, people say that the Gini impurity has a range of 0 to 0.5. However, when I calculate the gini impurity on a set of data with 3 possible values, the gini impurity I get is 0.544. The probabilities of each class are as follows:

```r
0.0    0.497562
1.0    0.453301
2.0    0.049137
```

The column on the right contains the probability for each of the values on the left. The calculated gini impurity is greater than 0.5. Can someone explain why this is, whether I did something wrong, and if the gini impurity should always be less than 0.5?